# Regex to match logfiles 1 to 11

Tags: regex, shell, unix

I would like to simply fetch logfiles 1 to 11 out of 500 with one regex:

```
log4j-cnode1.log.11  
log4j-cnode1.log.10  
log4j-cnode1.log.9  
log4j-cnode1.log.8  
log4j-cnode1.log.7  
log4j-cnode1.log.6  
log4j-cnode1.log.5  
log4j-cnode1.log.4  
log4j-cnode1.log.3  
log4j-cnode1.log.2  
log4j-cnode1.log.1
```

so I do not want to fetch log4j-cnode1.log.12, log4j-cnode1.log.13, ... , log4j-cnode1.log.500

I was trying this command:

```
find . -iname "log4j-cnode1*\.log\.(1[0-1]|[1-9])"
```

why does this not work?

1 to 9 works fine with this:

```
find . -iname "log4j-cnode1*\.log\.[1-9]"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `-iname` doesn't accept regular expressions, and even if it would, your `1*` would probably not be what you want. Use `-iregex`:

```
find -regextype posix-extended -iregex '(.*/)?log4j-cnode1.*\.log\.(1[0-1]|[1-9])'
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that `find` does not understand regex per default.

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -iname "log4j-cnode1*\.log\.(1?[0-9])"
```

Your Regex says 1 followed by 0 or 1 followed by 1-9

Comment: this would also display 12 to 19 which I didn't want

Answer (score 0):

```
$ find -name 'log4j-cnode1*\.log\.[0-9]*'
./log4j-cnode1.log.1
./log4j-cnode1.log.10
./log4j-cnode1.log.11
./log4j-cnode1.log.2
./log4j-cnode1.log.3
./log4j-cnode1.log.4
./log4j-cnode1.log.5
./log4j-cnode1.log.6
./log4j-cnode1.log.7
./log4j-cnode1.log.8
./log4j-cnode1.log.9
```

Answer (score 0):

You got it *almost* right.

But, instead of `-iname`, use `-iregex` with `-regextype egrep` (or `awk`), like this:

```
find . -regextype egrep \
    -iregex ".*log4j-cnode1.*\.log\.(1[0-1]|[1-9])"
```